# JavaScript function for drawing on canvas, which is called from aspx page, causes an error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, canvas

I need to call a javascript function from aspx page (C#). This is shor function is located in aspx file, and it draws a few figures. The function is invoked by button press. The parameters of figures are taken as some indexes from mssql database. The javascript code is invoked by the next command:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script language='javascript'>htm("+param+")</script>");
```

The problem is that if I put javascript function htm in the  section of aspx page, then I get a "htm function is not defined", in case if I put javascript at the end of the html code, I get error with getting canvas context (null object), because the canvas hasn't been loaded yet. The partial solution of the issue is assigning the javascript function to window.onload, but it is not the solution I need, because the figure must be drawn ***ONLY ONCE*** after button press.

Comment: Why don't you call javascript function on 'onclick' or 'OnClientClick' of button

Comment: The function actually runs on "onclick" action of button. I don't use "OnClientClick" action, because the function requires data, taken from database, and, as I understand, OnClientClick is not suitable for running code, which acts with server-side data.

Comment: what does `param` look like, what data it has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OnClientClick with server-side data if you can define it in server-side code:

```
myButton.OnClientClick = "htm(" + param + "); return false";
```

When this button is clicked - it will cause pure cleint-side click without any postback.

*UPDATE* If you do need to call it for server-side, you need to wait till function `htm` is defined, you can use timeout like this:

```
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "(function htmCaller() { if (typeof (htm) == 'undefined') { setTimeout(htmCaller, 500) } else { htm("+param+") })(); }", true);
```

Comment: This works on _PageLoad_ section, anyway, it doesn't work, if put this code in _Button1.Click_ event in CodeBehind. Sorry, I can't manage this.

Comment: You can put the code above in whenever you obtain your 'param'. And then since `OnClientClick` is pure-client click - it will be called *after* page has loaded - after all client-side objects are created

Comment: The problem is that I've put _OnClientClick_ in Button1.Click (the same button, for which OnClientClick is executed), and it doesn't even rise alert like myButton.OnClientClick = "alert('hey');";

Comment: That's strange, it should work. Can you make sure that server-side code that assigns that property is executed? Can you also explicitly cancel postback by returning false, e.g. `myButton.OnClientClick = "alert('hey'); return false";` ?

Comment: Server-side code is executed - the data for javascript processing are returned properly. I'he canceled postback - anyway, the alert doesn't work. It works only if I put code into PageLoad block.

Comment: Can you see the alert in HTML generated by ASPX markup and C# code?

Comment: No, it's not generated in HTML

Comment: Then the code to assign the property is not getting executed.

Comment: Where did you place the code if it's not in PageLoad? Where is your `param` is getting calculated?

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: You cannot put the code that creates *client-side* button click inside of the *server-side* button click - it has to be placed elsewhere. Why does PageLoad not working for you?

Comment: Because I need to transfer the data, obtained from server after button click to javascript function, and on PageLoad this function is evoked previously to obtaining data.

Comment: Ok, if you don't know the parameters until the actual click your original concept for server-side call was correct. But you need to wait for function "htm" to become defined - I updated my answer with one way to do it